# List Traefik ingress controllers using Go client for Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-go-client, traefik-ingress

We have a little internal tool listing our Kubernetes services using [Go client for Kubernetes](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes).

Now we have added Traefik to map our services to meaningful dns names using ingress controllers. We see that there is an [ingress lister extension](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/listers/extensions/v1beta1/ingress.go) in Go client for Kubernetes that can be used to list ingress controllers. However, we could not make it work.

Are there any Go client code snippets listing ingress controllers?

Comment: "However, we could not make it work." – please provide samples of the code you have already tried, so we have some of your prior art to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried so far? Posting examples helps. Try the following arbitrary example to get you started:

```
    // imports
    // metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    // "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    // "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"

    // create the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
    }
    for {
            ingressList, err := clientset.ExtensionsV1beta1().Ingresses("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})
            if err != nil {
                    // handle err
            }
            ingressCtrls := ingressList.Items
            if len(ingressCtrls) > 0 {
                    for _, ingress := range ingressCtrls {
                            fmt.Printf("ingress %s exists in namespace %s\n", ingress.Name, ingress.Namespace)
                    }
            } else {
                    fmt.Println("no ingress found")
            }
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
```